# DropWizard testing

Tags: testing, yaml, dropwizard

As I am using eclipse and just set up a dropwizard server.  On the command prompt I typed in java -jar target/hello-world-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar server hello-world.yml and is running.  Yet when ever I make a change to my eclipse file, like changing the yml file for example it doesn't update.  I have to crtl+c and re-run what I typed in above.  My question is, is there a faster way of testing so that it updates every time I change something or I just have to deal with the testing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Run from within the IDE**

Different Java IDEs permit more efficient workflows. For example, in an IDE you can run up your application using a Runtime Configuration that executes your `Service.main()` method with parameters of `server hello-world.yml`. This will save you endless Maven builds.

Unfortunately, with Eclipse the hot swapping of code changes is often cumbersome, so I would recommend that you [consider Intellij](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/24231/7167) which is more reliable when it comes to hot swapping code. Even then hot swapping can be risky.

**Sometimes a restart is unavoidable**

That being said, in your situation hot swapping won't help. You are changing the startup configuration file which is only read at startup. You will have to restart to see the changes unless you create your own dynamic-refresh-on-file-hash-change mechanism (not advised).

One alternative is to put much of your configuration testing in unit tests and verify that your code is responding as expected.

**Static assets give an optimal workflow (no restarts)**

You may encounter a situation where you only want to change static assets (like JavaScript files) in which case Intellij will allow you to simply recompile on the fly and will copy the changed assets into the `/target` directory and have them immediately picked up by Dropwizard without a restart.

If you wanted to go one step further you could enlist the services of Grunt.js so that it continuously monitored the `src/main/resources/assets` (or similar) for changes and then automatically update your `/target` for you. Again, Intellij will autosave on focus change so this would lead to an optimal workflow where you change the asset, wait one second, refresh browser and see the immediate result.

I wrote a lengthy blog article covering [Dropwizard and Ember Data](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2013/05/11/dropwizard-with-ember-data/) a while ago if you want more details on this approach (and single page web application development in general).

Comment: This is correct. The only thing I'd add is that you should set `http.shutdownGracePeriod` to `0s` for your development environment, which will allow Jetty to immediately shut down.